# Identifying single overlapping features from GeoServer layer

Tags: postgis, geoserver, shapefile, openlayers-2, overlapping-features

I'm trying to use GeoServer to display features from a PostGis table the url will look similar to this.

Example URL

Localhost:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=cite:Layer1, cite:Layer2& styles=&bbox……..width=512,heaight=430&srs=EPSG:4326&application/openlayers

```
&FILTER= (<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
               <FeatureId fid=”Layer1.1234”></FeaturId>
               <FeatureId fid=”Layer1.5678”></FeaturId></Filter>)
            (<Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <FeatureId fid=”Layer2.345”></FeaturId></Filter>)
```

When I click on a polygon I need to highlight a single polygon if two (or more) polygons overlap i need to be able to step through each polygon in turn showing just it's attributes.

At present I click on a feature and the attributes for the entire layer are shown.

In my example I use PostGIS but I've also tried this using a shapefile and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to make sure that the filter is attached to the end of the getFeatureInfo request that you are sending.